# track order animation based on status as represented in image

Tags: android

I have a task to do track order with animation.  Need to show pointer moving to the location based on status and changes its color. I search for some references and disappointed on it. can someone help me through this where I need to start this from?

sample image:

[image: sample image]

Comment: `just like Amazon track order`? What that ? Read [ask].

Comment: Still not clear enough . Maybe you should add some graphical representation for the expected output .

Comment: @ADM done. I just added graphical representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a custom view, from your image it is best to build your own custome view seekbar as vertical direction.

See an example of custome view seekbar in this library:
https://github.com/channguyen/range-slider-view

To help you where you should start from? check these links:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components
https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view